# IE11 & justify-content issue

Tags: css, angular

My angular 6 application is running both on IE 11 & Chrome latest version. There in I have two button seperated by each other using below CSS3.

```
.my widget .my footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 3px auto 6px;
}
```

Using above CSS it works great in Chrome browser and buttons gets separated with each other with some space in beween, However on IE11 when I inspect that I see red line in CSS under

```
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

I tried with `justify-content:space-between` but I still see buttons are attached to each other with no space in between.

Comment: See: [https://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content](https://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content) for the support of a given feature (searchable) in major browsers. This site highlights known issues and provides extra resources. Well worth keeping in your webdev arsenal.

Comment: agree, can you please help me with solution if you can

Comment: You may look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698258/other-ways-to-justify-content-space-between/60698473#60698473 might be a duplicate  test it in IE11 : https://jsbin.com/rapituduvi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: the short answer could be : `button + button {margin-left:auto;` You might  share the html output if this is not just button inside a flex container  ..

Comment: I did not get you, can you please elaborate more on this

Comment: use margin instead justify-content. but without your html and css , there is possibly another reason elsewhere. justify-content is supposed to work in IE11. add enough code to demonstrate your issue, so we can reproduce your issue. beside, testing IE11 requires a genuine IE11 for reliable  CSS test ;)

Comment: justify-conent works but space evenly does not work in IE11, however can we have fall back if it does not work in IE11

Answer (score 3):

I have used `space-around` as below to  make things work.

```
 justify-content: space-around;
```

This works both in IE11 & chrome.
Thanks @ G-Cyrillus for looking into this.